# Extra directory can be created in hg rename-ing directory

Tags: mercurial

I try to rename directory which includes largefile-normal mixed via `hg rename <orig-dir> <dest-dir>`, and results as this:

- `orig/foo.png`(largefile) → `dest/orig/foo.png`
- `orig/bar.txt`(normal) → `dest/bar.txt`
  ...

I'm annoyed by this behavior, I'd like to know how to resolve this problem.

Comment: Are you saying that the largefile status gets lost?

Comment: In trying to `hg rename --after` moved parent directory of largefiles causes lost status the largefiles. And trying to `hg rename` parent directory of largiles causes original directory named subdirectory was created and moved largefiles that subdirectory into renamed directory.

Comment: There is a log when I reproduce this issue: https://pastebin.com/gBq6fAke Sorry I couldn't provide a log in English.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are seeing is because the folder has a file which isn't tracked by mercurial.

Workaround might be to rename the folder then run `hg rename --after`

For example (windows):

```
  ren orig dest
  hg rename --after orig dest
```

Comment: I tryed like this, results is: rename `orig/foo.png` to `dest/foo.png` largefile by explorer and `hg rename --after`, mercurial said that files not exist.